# Search values in a large json file in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, hash

So I'm learning ruby and i have to find specific values in a large JSON.
I need to get this field but I'm not able to do it.

I have this json:

```
[{"origen"=>                                                  
    {"productor"=>"Agencia Estatal de Meteorología - AEMET. Gobierno de España",
     "web"=>"https://www.aemet.es",                              "enlace"=>"https://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/prediccion/municipios/horas/lagran-id01030",
     "language"=>"es",                                         
     "copyright"=>"© AEMET. Autorizado el uso de la información y su reproducción citando a AEMET como autora de la misma.",
     "notaLegal"=>"https://www.aemet.es/es/nota_legal"},         
   "elaborado"=>"2022-03-30T22:43:40",                         
   "nombre"=>"Lagrán",                                         
   "provincia"=>"Araba/Álava",
   "prediccion"=>
    {"dia"=>
      [{"estadoCielo"=>
         [{"value"=>"16", "periodo"=>"20", "descripcion"=>"Cubierto"},
          {"value"=>"16n", "periodo"=>"21", "descripcion"=>"Cubierto"},
          {"value"=>"82n", "periodo"=>"22", "descripcion"=>"Bruma"},
          {"value"=>"16n", "periodo"=>"23", "descripcion"=>"Cubierto"}],
        "precipitacion"=>[{"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"20"}, {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"21"}, {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"22"}, {"value"=>"Ip", "periodo"=>"23"}],
        "probPrecipitacion"=>[{"value"=>"5", "periodo"=>"2002"}],
        "probTormenta"=>[{"value"=>"5", "periodo"=>"2002"}],
        "nieve"=>[{"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"20"}, {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"21"}, {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"22"}, {"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"23"}],
        "probNieve"=>[{"value"=>"0", "periodo"=>"2002"}],
     "temperatura"=>[{"value"=>"7", "periodo"=>"21"}, {"value"=>"6", "periodo"=>"22"}, {"value"=>"6", "periodo"=>"23"}],      
        "sensTermica"=>[{"value"=>"4", "periodo"=>"21"}, {"value"=>"2", "periodo"=>"22"}, {"value"=>"3", "periodo"=>"23"}],     
        "humedadRelativa"=>[{"value"=>"81", "periodo"=>"21"}, {"value"=>"84", "periodo"=>"22"}, {"value"=>"87", "periodo"=>"23"}]
        "vientoAndRachaMax"=>
         [{"direccion"=>["N"], "velocidad"=>["15"], "periodo"=>"21"},
          {"value"=>"45", "periodo"=>"21"},
          {"direccion"=>["NO"], "velocidad"=>["19"], "periodo"=>"22"},
          {"value"=>"39", "periodo"=>"22"},
          {"direccion"=>["N"], "velocidad"=>["15"], "periodo"=>"23"},
          {"value"=>"44", "periodo"=>"23"}],

        "fecha"=>"2022-03-30T00:00:00",

        "orto"=>"07:56",
        "ocaso"=>"20:34"},
```

And I want the field `"fecha"=>"2022-03-30T00:00:00",`

And I'm trying this:

```
def json json
  puts json[0].select {|json| json["fecha"]}
end
```

And the output is this:
{}
so i understand that I'm doing badly cuz I'm getting blank output.

Any idea what's going on there?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use pictures. Provide inputs and outputs, and show the code and errors you're having issues with.

Comment: done!@ToddA.Jacobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in order to navigate through a *Hash* ( Because what you shared is not a JSON itself, but a ruby hash. ), you can use the `dig` method.
--> Example of usage here: https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/dig ( I recommend reading the rails docs on it too. )

What you shared is not a valid hash either, but I attempted closing the missing brackets myself and this worked.
Try this:

```
def json json 
 json.dig(0, 'prediccion', 'dia', 0, 'fecha')
end
```

This is assuming that you always want the first element of the root array and the first element of the `dia` array.

If you wanted to fetch them dynamically, you would have to loop through them and replace the 0s with loop indexes.

Comment: Something like `json.map { |item| item["prediccion"]["dia"].map { |subitem| subitem["fecha"] } }` would work (depending on what exactly OP wants).